# Where can i find code for a compiler?

Tags: compilation

So I am trying to make a small programming language as a project. But the thing is I have no clue how to begin. I know how a compiler works and all but don't know how the code would be written for it. I searched everywhere for example for the code of any compiler but couldn't find anything. Where would I find this, or could someone explain to me the format and method I should use for creating the compiler? Also if you were wondering I am thinking of using c++ for writing the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend taking a free [online course](http://online.stanford.edu/course/compilers-0) in Compiler Construction.  Guided material and thoughtfully designed coursework is the best way to ease into this sort of thing, in my opinion.

Comment: thatnkyou, but I understand how this works though. I will accept your answer but all I really need is guidelines for the code. I have watched many tutorials and read a ton of documentation on this subject. All I am looking for is guidance on how to write the code. Not how it works but how to write it.

Comment: A good course will guide you along with relevant assignments that will teach you how to write the code, a little at a time.  It’s not just going to be lectures on theory.  Modern compilers for ‘real’ languages are _huge_.  Follow the coursework and learn to write a simple compiler, _then_ go digging in LLVM, GCC, Roslyn, etc.

Answer (score 0):

LLVM.org; open source modern C, C++, Objective-C and more